# vscode is not lauching for me on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I downloaded the latest ZIP file of VSCode for windows from VSCode website.
Unzipped it and tried running the Code.exe from it. It does nothing no crashing message juts output nothing.
I tried running Code.exe from command prompt [after CD to the directory where I have unzipped it], nothing happens, no out put.
Then I did some googling to do more troubleshooting and found out I need to run Code.exe or bin\code.cmd with --help and --verbose command.
No output on command line.

I am totally confused and don't know how do I make VScode work on my windows 7 machine or how do I troubleshoot why its not working.

I have appropriate .Net Framework installed [the one suggested by the VSCode website].

I have also tried installer , with all above debugging steps , same outcome as above.

I checked the code.exe in task manager to see if its running in background, nothing in there too.

What do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the process is running in Task Manager.

Check for "code.exe". If it is running, then end all instances, and try again.

Otherwise, try opening event log, in Application or System. Look for errors or warnings which may have been logged and give some insight into why Code didn't open.

Answer (score 0):

So guys seems like new version of VSCode has this problem.
Try downloading an older version of VSCode and do not upgrade it once its installed.

After I installed : V 1.18.1 , its working fine.